# C - getline() and strcmp() issue

Tags: c, getline, strcmp

I am having an issue where I can not find a specific word in a file with strcmp() when using getline.

My file looks something like this:

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
section1
Word4
```

This is the code I have right now:

```
while(found == 0)
{
    getline(&input, &len, *stream);
    if (feof(*stream))
        break;

    if(strcmp(input, "section1\n") == 0)
    {
        printf("End of section\n");
        found = 1;
    }
}
```

strcmp() never returns 0 though.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Made an edit to the code.  I transferred it incorrectly.

Solution from the comments:
I need to add \r to the string being compared

```
if(strcmp(input, "section1\r\n") == 0)
```

Comment: what BLUEPIXY mentioned, also, are you doing this on Windows (where newline is \r\n)?

Comment: Does your file use `\r\n` endings?  Also, you're missing a parenthesis in your `if` expression, so this shouldn't compile...

Comment: @iharob because he wants to jump out if he finds the line, rather than processing the rest of the file, presumably

Comment: what is `stream`? if it is `FILE* stream;` then the arguments to `getline`/`feof` shouldn't be `*stream`, but only `stream`.

Comment: Please post real code this one wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Thanks Eric!  I needed to include the \r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove potential end-of-line character(s), then compare.

```
getline(&input, &len, *stream);
input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = 0;
if(strcmp(input, "section1") == 0)
{
    printf("End of section\n");
    found = 1;
}
```

Notes: With `getline()`, the buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.  Wise to check the return value from `getline()`.

Comment: Since `getline()` returns the number of characters in the line it read, you can speed up the removal of the newline by capturing the return value.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler True about the speed up using various code and `len`.  Though typically  the speed-up pales to the time spent in `getline()` itself.  [Trimming fgets(): strlen() or strtok()](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/67756)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `feof` is not needed in this situation. You are using `getline` and `strcmp` to test the line. Use the return from `getline` to test whether to continue reading. A correct implementation would be similar to:

```
while (getline(&input, &len, *stream) != -1)
{
    if(strcmp (input, "section1\n") == 0)
    {
        printf("End of section\n");
        found = 1;
        break;  /* if you want to terminate read when found=1 */
    }
}
```

To eliminate the problem with dangling `newlines` at the end of each line read, simply remove them. `getline` makes this quite simple as it returns the number of characters actually read -- eliminating the need to call `strlen`. Simply capture the return of `getline` in a variable, and remove the `newline` (or both `carriage return` & `newline` if using DOS line ends) as follows:

```
ssize_t nchr = 0;   /* number of characters actually read */

while ((nchr = getline (&input, &len, *stream)) != -1)
{
    /* strip trailing '\n' or '\r' */
    while (nchr > 0 && (input[nchr-1] == '\n' || input[nchr-1] == '\r'))
        input[--nchr] = 0;
    ...
```

Comment: Good to see code checking `getline()` result and testing `read > 0` in while loop, 2 things often missed. +1

Comment: Too many `valgrind` **invalid read of size 1** errors not to check for `read > 0`. See, even a blind squirrel can find a nut every once in a while `:p`

Comment: 'read' is the name of a system function.   Should not use system function names for variable names.

Comment: regarding this line: 'if(strcmp(input, "section1\n") == 0)'  the code can ignore line endings considerations by using: 'if(strncmp(input, "section1", sizeof "section1") == 0)'

Comment: That will not work. You must subtract `1` from `sizeof literal`, otherwise you are including the `null-terminating` character in the count. With `-1` it is a great improvement - along with your catch of `read`. Fixing.

Comment: The trouble with using `strncmp()` is that this will identify `section10` and `section100` etc as being `section1`.

Comment: Not limited to `8` characters it won't `:p`

Comment: Oh Oh I see what you are saying. You are correct -- re-fixing `:(`